# Solving a system of coupled ODEs

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to solve these 9 coupled ODEs

```
(v1[t] - t) n1'[t] + n1[t] v1'[t] == 0, 

3 sigma1 n1[t] n1'[t] + (v1[t] - t) v1'[t] +phi'[t] == 0,

(v2[t] - t) n2'[t] + n2[t] v2'[t] == 0, 

3 Q sigma2 n2[t] n2'[t] + (v2[t] - t) v2'[t] + Q phi'[t] == 0, 

phi'[t] - (1/ne[t]) ne'[t] == 0, 

phi'[t] - (sigmas1/ns1[t]) ns1'[t] == 0, 

(vs20 + vs2[t] - t) ns2'[t] + ns2[t] vs2'[t] == 0, 

3 Qs2 sigmas2 ns2[t] ns2'[t] + (vs20 + vs2[t] - t) vs2'[t] + Qs2 phi'[t] == 0,

a n1'[t] + b n2'[t] - ne'[t] - c ns1'[t] + d ns2'[t] == 0,
```

My problem is that I have a precision error that I can't fix probably due to the initial values.

Please, is there a numerical method to evaluate the initial conditions for each variable before solving the ODE?

```
sol = NDSolve[{(v1[t] - t) n1'[t] + n1[t] n1'[t] == 0, 3 sigma1 n1[t] n1'[t] 
  + (v1[t] - t) v1'[t] + phi'[t] == 0, (v2[t] - t) n2'[t] + n2[t] v2'[t] == 
 0, 3 Q sigma2 n2[t] n2'[t] + (v2[t] - t) v2'[t] + Q phi'[t] == 0, phi'[t] - 
 (1/ne[t]) ne'[t] == 0, phi'[t] - (sigmas1/ns1[t]) ns1'[t] == 0, (vs20 + 
 vs2[t]- t) ns2'[t] + ns2[t] vs2'[t] == 0, 3 Qs2 sigmas2 ns2[t] ns2'[t] + 
 (vs20+vs2[t]- t) vs2'[t] + Qs2 phi'[t] == 0, a n1'[t] + b n2'[t] - ne'[t] - c 
 ns1'[t] + d ns2'[t] == 0, n1[0] == 3, v1[0] == 1, phi[0] == 0, n2[0] == 0.52, 
 v2[0] == 0.25,ne[0] == ns1[0] == ns2[0] == 0, vs2[0] == 0.1}, {n1, v1, phi, 
n2, v2, ne, ns1, ns2, vs2}, {t, 0, 0.9}, WorkingPrecision -> 50, PrecisionGoal    
-> 30]
```

> NDSolve::precw: The precision of the differential equation (.......) is less than WorkingPrecision (50.`).

the plots give

```
 Block[{vs20 = 6, Q = 1/8, Qs2 = 1, sigma1 = 0.25, sigma2 = 0.25,sigmas1 = 1, 
 sigmas2 = 1, a = 0.335, b = 0.564, c = 1.9, d =3},Plot[Evaluate[{n1[t],v1[t], 
 phi[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, 0.9},PlotRange -> {-1, 4}, PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
 PlotLegends -> {"n1", "v1", "phi"}]]
```

[image: plot]
Please, someone for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `DSolve` (without timerange):

```
DSolve[{(v1[t] - t) n1'[t] + n1[t] n1'[t] == 0, 
3 sigma1 n1[t] n1'[t] + (v1[t] - t) v1'[t] + phi'[t] == 
0, (v2[t] - t) n2'[t] + n2[t] v2'[t] == 0, 
3 Q sigma2 n2[t] n2'[t] + (v2[t] - t) v2'[t] + Q phi'[t] == 0, 
phi'[t] - (1/ne[t]) ne'[t] == 0, 
phi'[t] - (sigmas1/ns1[t]) ns1'[t] == 
0, (vs20 + vs2[t] - t) ns2'[t] + ns2[t] vs2'[t] == 0, 3 Qs2 sigmas2 ns2[t] ns2'[t] + (vs20 + vs2[t] - t) vs2'[t] + 
Qs2 phi'[t] == 0, a  n1'[t] + b n2'[t] - ne'[t] - c ns1'[t] + d ns2'[t] == 0, 
n1[0] == 3, v1[0] == 1, phi[0] == 0, n2[0] == 0.52, v2[0] == 0.25, 
ne[0] == ns1[0] == ns2[0] == 0, vs2[0] == 0.1}
, {n1, v1, phi, n2,v2, ne, ns1, ns2, vs2}, t]

(*{{n1 -> Function[{t}, 3], n2 -> Function[{t}, 0.52], 
ne -> Function[{t}, 0], ns1 -> Function[{t}, 0], 
ns2 -> Function[{t}, 0], phi -> Function[{t}, 0], 
v1 -> Function[{t}, 1], v2 -> Function[{t}, 0.25], 
vs2 -> Function[{t}, 0.1]}}*)
```

**alternatively** 
Rationalize your equation before applying `NDSolve`!

Comment: But I get the same plots @Ulrich Neumann

Comment: without  error message and no precision issue

Comment: @gallagher `precw` is merely a warning, it doesn't necessarily mean the result is wrong.

Comment: Now when I try to plot the output, I always get the plot above, i.e. constant values for all solutions. I made a mistak?

Comment: @Gallagher What should be the solution? What does this model describe?

Comment: @Alex Trounev These equations describe an hydrodynamic approach proposed for plasma expansion in an ionized medium

Comment: @Alex Trounev Why I always get constant values for all solutions `n1`, `v1`, `phi1`. Normally it varies, right?

Comment: @Gallagher The system of equations has the form $m.f'=0$. Therefore $f=f(0)=const$ is a solution. To exit $f(0)$ you need to add something to the system.

Comment: @Alex Trounev Like what for example? I only have the initial conditions since I deal with linear ODE.

Comment: @Gallagher The system of equations is nonlinear since it has the form $m(f,t).f'=0$. There is another branch of the solution. To get on it you need to set the excitement on the right side.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103501/discussion-between-gallagher-and-alex-trounev).